# Let image if nil disappear in swift 3 (or shrink so it looks like it disappeared)

Tags: ios, swift, image, cell

I am quite new to developing.
I am currently working on a clone of Instagram to learn the basic stuff.

Currently I have a fin working app with all the upload, like and fav details, Instagram offers.

Now I want to do the following:

1. I have one screen where you can choose a pic (but don't have to) and a caption.
2. If the user decides to post no pic and maybe just a couple of lines (like a joke or some interesting stuff or riddles), the uploadedImage in my cell - which is empty and optional then) - disappears and the whole cell shrinks to fit the content.
   I will upload 2 pictures so you can understand better how to do it.

Do you know how and where to let the image if nil for this cell disappear? All posts should be displayed on the same cell and fitted properly.
Thanks, I hope I said it clearly.

[This is also the feed but now with a post without image, where the UIImageView is blank. I want the empty image to disappear for this reusable cell, so that it shrinks and has no white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltk1V.png)
[This is how the post should look like if the user decides to post a post without picture. They all should use the same reusable cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPQIL.png)

ups can only attach 2 pictures as my reputation is too low, I could send the 3rd via chat if you need it, it shows the cell as it is in Instagram (copied) The pic 1 shows the cell and where the blank space is is usually the uploaded picture

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Vertical UIStackView for your content, constrain it to the top and bottom of the contentView of the tableView cell and set the tableView to use [UITableViewAutomaticDimension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html) then the stackview will calculate its intrinsic size from the size of its children (and the imageview will contribute 0 hieght when its nil).  the tableView cell will then resize to always be proportional to the height of the image.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I already have it with all the constraints and I am using tableviewAutomaticDimension, thats why I have different big sizes of Cell. Large photos with height of 400, smaller with 200 are all properly handled. Still if nil it does not disappear

Comment: Oh you want the whole cell to disappear.  Don't do this with constraints; the padding will still appear when there is no image.  Do this in your model.  instead of basing the number of cells in your tableview and the data in cellforRow(at:) base it on a filtered list.  filteredData = data.flatmap { $0.image == nil ? nil : $0}

Comment: Nono just the UIImage which presents the uploaded picture in case the users decided to share one, sorry for the wrong hint ^^. I meant that the UIImage adjusts to the height of the uploaded picture, the whole cell therefor as well